# I can not read the file without errors with language of the file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, scene

I cannot read files that finish with .docx without got errors with my reading.
I need help with the language that shows on component of javaFx.

```
    public void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    File file = null;


    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File ("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Software Engineering\\Final Courses\\Final Project\\Projects on Eclipse\\Project Lab"));
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("DOCX Files", "*.docx"));
    //FileInputStream fileChooser = new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getAbsolutePath());
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
    FileReader reader = null;
    //BufferedReader reader = null;
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(selectedFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectedFile));
    String content;

    reader = new FileReader(selectedFile);
    char[] chars = new char[(int) selectedFile.length()];
    reader.read(chars);
    content = new String(chars);

    reader.close();
    if(selectedFile != null) {
            textFile.getItems().add(content);
    } else {
            System.out.println("file is not valid");
    }


}
```

Comment: Any reason you open the file 3 times? Also what do you want to read from the `docx` file? The `.docx` file format is much more complex than a plain text file. Reading it as a string results in data that is not intelligble to most people, if it produces a valid string at all.

Comment: docx files are binary files, reading them as text will just give you garbage.

Comment: Apache should have something you can use to read `.docx` files.

Comment: For some reason windows not shown me .txt files , so I thought .docs file are the same method.